# Change local branch remote origin to new one in GIT

Tags: git

I checked out a branch let's call `1.14` from the remote `1.14` branch. I made local changes and made a commit, changed my local branch to something else, let's call `mynew`. If I run `git branch -vv` I see that

> mynew   efe918d   [origin/1.14: ahead 1]    commit_msg

Now I want to push this `mynew` not into the `origin/1.14` but a new let's call `origin/mynew`, which isn't exist yet, I want to create it by pushing the local one.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the destination branch on `push` command

```
git push origin localBranch:remoteBranch
```

In your case you can write

```
git push origin mynew:mynew
```

If `mynew`doesn't exist on the server, it will create it.

To set up `mynew` local branch to be linked (when pulling,  pushing) to remote `mynew` branch use `-u` or `--set-upstream` equivalent option

```
git push -u origin mynew:mynew
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on `mynew` 's branch, `git push -u origin mynew` will push on a new branch called mynew.

Comment: There are some cases and settings where this will work, and some where `mynew:mynew` is required. It's always safe to be explicit (`mynew:mynew`) so Flows' answer is better here.

Answer (score 1):

Just Push your local `mynew` branch. A new `origin/mynew` will be created and track automatically.

```
$ git checkout mynew
$ git push -u origin mynew
```

Answer (score 0):

This pushes the `mynew` branch to `origin` and sets its upstream to the new created `origin/mynew`.

```
git push origin mynew --set-upstream
```